# Get data from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewPage()
{
    Obj object = new Obj();
    object.id = 3;
    var JsonItem = Model.getItem(object);

    return Json(JsonRfc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Client-side

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON({
        url: 'ViewPage',
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not logging anything in my console (`console.log(data)` returns nothing).  What am I missing here?  When I click on the ActionLink `ViewPage`, it should go into the model and do some stuff. After I want to get it from the client-side to generate a list view.

Comment: Are you sure it is getting to your Action?

Comment: Yes, the View being rendered shows the JSON object.  I want to grab this with the $.getJSON method.

Comment: The "data" variable will already be a JavaScript object.  You need to specify the success handler, like the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are missing something.
Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON({
        url: 'ViewPage',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```